# "Laravel 5.1" add user and project with userId

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a form where an user can post a project to the database together with making a new user where both are linked together.

Usersid and projects.user_id values in the table.But, I have a small problem. If I get the last id from the users table and use that one +1 for the next id it works. but if an user gets deleted before adding the new project with id it can get really messy when the application launches.

let's say I got the last user as id 5 in the table. but, someone deleted it and I made a new project with a new user the day after.Now the next id will be id 6. but according to my code it reflects 5 in the projects_table but in the users_table it becomes 6.

I was wondering if someone can suggest me a function that I could use for having the right id's?

function for getting the last id

```
    public static function getLastRow(){
            $data =  DB::table('users')->select('id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->first();
            return $data->id;
        }
```

before validator i count the last id for adding it to projects

```
 $lastidplus = (int)User::getLastRow() + 1;
```

in my validator i have this :

```
'user_id' => $lastidplus,
```

NOTE:: this works but if in the future the last row in the users table gets deleted. there will come an chain reaction of false ids in the corresponding projects table as he will always have 1 difference. and I wantto make that impossible.

Comment: thanks @Raj for making it a bit nicer. will pay more attention when making a post again!

Comment: since your English is not good enough, can you include some code in your question so we can understand better

Comment: @StefanoGroenland ur always wlcm

Comment: saying it simple ; when I make a new project throught a form it includes making an user row aswel. but i can't get the id there yet so i have to check the last row from the database. The problem there can occur that if the last user let say id 5 was deleted. the mysql engine would automaticly make the next user id 6 so there would be a gap between id 4 and id 6. which is normal. but then in the projects table where after i counted the last id + 1 (getLastRow()) will show 5 instead of 6. @Digitlimit

Comment: That's why I suggested including your code in your question so we can see what you are doing. Are you using the create method? if so, then the id of the newly created record is returned like so `$user = User::create(['name'=>'Stefano']); $id = $user->id`

Comment: Oh hold on! after reading this i came up to : `$user = User::create(...)`
`'gebruiker_id' => $user->id` and guess what it worked! @Digitlimit please add is as an answer as it helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the ID of a newly created record try:

```
$user = User::create(['name'=>'Stefano']);
$user->id
```

Comment: made it with  `$user = User::create(...)`  `'gebruiker_id' => $user->id` thanks for giving me and idea!